# How to convert string to oracle clob for insert database?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I want to insert string to oracle database as clob data type in c#. How can I do this? some codes for example:

```
  private static byte[] GetByteArr(string listParameter)
    {
        if (listParameter!=null)
        {
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(listParameter);
        }
        else
        {
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(string.Empty);
        }
    }
  byte[] toArr = GetByteArr((string)eMessageList[1]);
  emailParameters[1] = command.Parameters.Add("pEto",OracleDbType.Clob, toArr,ParameterDirection.Input);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

this code insert `toArr` to database as `System.Byte[]`.

Comment: If it's a clob (rather than a blob) you shouldn't need to convert it to a byte array. You *might* need to convert it to a `char[]`, but not a `byte[]`... Additionally, you haven't said anything about what happens with the code you've already provided.

Comment: I haven't said anything about what happens, because some comments isn't releated about my operation, it's about what I do. I just want to learn insert string to db as clob data type.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
byte[] newvalue = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(mystring);
var clob = new OracleClob(db);
clob.Write(newvalue, 0, newvalue.Length);
```

Comment: Works for me. One points to note the database connection passed to OracleClob must be open.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question seems to be outdated, I want to share an example that worked for me.

My intention was to save a JSON string (with more than 32k characters) into a clob field.

This is what I did:

```
string JSON_string = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SomeObject);
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", SomeAttribute);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", SomeAttribute2);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", SomeAttribute3);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", JSON_string);
```

And then execute the command. I'm using our companies library to do that:

```
DataSet myDS = myUser.myLoginUser._MySpAppS.RunSQL("INSERT INTO MARS$T_BCSAVINGS (MASSNAHMEN_ID, USER_ID, AKTIV, HEBELDATEI) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", myCommand.Parameters);
```

I'm saving the result in a DataSet only to check if the query was successful.

So basically what I did, is to handover the string to the OleDbCommand parameters list and executed the query with those parameters.